# Angular - Fetch data using angular service

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am trying to fetch details. So, here is my code.

data.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import { HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse } from 
 '@angular/common/http';
 import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';


 export class DataService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 userdetails() {
  return this.http.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
  }

}
```

home.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { DataService } from '../data.service';
  import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { userInfo } from 'os';
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
  })
  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user:any

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit()
   {
     this.data.userdetails().subscribe(
      allData => {
      this.user = allData;
      return this.user;
   });

   }
   }
```

home.component.html

```
 <div *ngFor="let x of allData">
   {{{x.name}}
 </div>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am getting some syntax error in home.component.ts and other error like "Can't resolve all parameters for DataService: (?)." . Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try code below or seen: [API IN ANGULAR 7](http://hoanguyenit.com/login-state-in-angular-7-+-laravel-5-4.html)

```js
File servive when request API, you need add
    const httpOptions = {
      headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    };

    /*
    * METHOD POST
    */
    sendpost(value: any) {
        return this.http.post<any>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', value,httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(user => {
                return user;
            }));
    }

    /**
     * METHOD GET
     */
    getdetails(){
        return this.http.get<any>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .pipe(map(item => {
                return item;
            }));
    }

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
File HomeComponent.ts: you import file serivice
import {UserService} from '../_services/user.services'
dataItem:any = {} 
 constructor(private _userService:UserService){
       this._userService.getdetails().subscribe(item=>{
            console.log(item);
            this.dataItem=item;
        })
 }
 
 
------------------------------------------
show HomeComponent.html

<ul *ngIf="dataItem?.length>0">
    <li *ngFor='let item of dataItem'>
        {{item.name}} - {{item.username}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `Injectable` decorator to your DataService class.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

}
```

https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable

Additional notes below thanks to JB Nizet.

- All your subscribes in your `OnInit` should end by a `;` not a `,`.
- `allData` doesn't exist as property in your component. `<div *ngFor="let x of allData">` won't work.

Comment: I tried that code but it still showing so many errors. I hope you have understood the problem statements. Please help me out with code to solve this problem.

Comment: Initial problem was because of the missing of Injectable keyword. Other things to fix should be in a new question I think.